# False Duplicate Content On Moz Report

Tags: seo, htaccess, web-development, 301-redirect, duplicate-content

We are using Salesforce's Visualforce to run one of our websites.

We use Moz to monitor SEO issues.

Moz has identified more issues pages than we have - see the attached image. We have only a few thousand pages at best. However Google and Moz are taking keywords and adding it to the end of the domain and creating a URL that doesn't exist. Recently I made all of these URLs redirect to the home page to see if it resolved the issue - it didn't and the URLs that don't exist are still being crawled.

What do I do - this is effecting my rank. Please help?

[image]

Comment: Do you have canonical tags on your pages?

Comment: I don't however the issue is that Google and Moz are crawling URLs that aren't real - they should be landing on 404 pages - but I have redirected them to the home page. Here is an example URL: https://www.example.com.au/Australia/Whitsundays/Australia/Whitsundays/Australia/Whitsundays

Comment: There's your answer then: update your code to return a 404 on invalid URLs. Redirecting them all to the homepage really isn't what you want.

Comment: I have changed it to 404 redirect - I have requested Moz recrawl but that may take up to 48 hours. I'll keep you posted - thank you for your help

Comment: Cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34583009/1591669

Comment: The other has been deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMS was just trying to serve broken pages on unreal URLs. I had to add a small php script that identified if the URL was valid or not. If the your was invalid it would redirect to a 404 page